# How can I set an onclicklistener after getting creating my recylerview?

Tags: android, kotlin

You may be able to tell that I'm in a very early stage of learning android development. I come from php (Magento) where we don't really have multithreading and I feel like that's what I might be falling over with this.

I have a main activity where I load a recycler view that gets data from my database with a lifecyclescoped corountine but on my main activity there's also a button that I had a onclicklistener on but it's no longer triggering since I created the recycler view. It isn't throwing any errors that I am aware of either.

Here's the code:

```
package com.example.todo

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import com.example.todo.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private lateinit var db: TodoDatabase

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        db = TodoDatabase.getInstance(this@MainActivity)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        val save: Button = binding.button
        val todo: TextInputEditText = binding.todoInput

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            getUncheckedTodos()
        }

        save.setOnClickListener {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                save(todo.text.toString())
                todo.text?.clear()
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun getUncheckedTodos() {
        val todos = db.todoDao().getUnchecked()
        val adapter = CustomAdapter(todos)
        recyclerView = binding.recyclerView
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager(this))
    }

    private suspend fun save(todo: String) {
        if (todo.isNotEmpty()) {
            db.todoDao().upsert(Todo(id = null, description = todo, checked = false))
        }
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.todo

import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Delete
import androidx.room.Query
import androidx.room.Upsert

@Dao
interface TodoDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Todo")
    suspend fun getAll(): List<Todo>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Todo WHERE checked = 0")
    suspend fun getUnchecked(): List<Todo>

    @Upsert
    suspend fun upsert(vararg todo: Todo)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(todo: Todo)
}
```

```
package com.example.todo

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class CustomAdapter(private val dataSet: List<Todo>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    /**
     * Provide a reference to the type of views that you are using
     * (custom ViewHolder)
     */
    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val textView: TextView

        init {
            // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View
            textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView3)
        }
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        // Create a new view, which defines the UI of the list item
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_row, viewGroup, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        // Get element from your dataset at this position and replace the
        // contents of the view with that element
        viewHolder.textView.text = dataSet[position].description
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun getItemCount() = dataSet.size

}
```

I want to be able to add items to my TODO table and show them in a recyclerview in the same activiy(?)

Comment: Is there any kind of crash or just RecyclerView isn't updating?

Comment: @AbdullahJaved - The button no longer works. The recyclerview seems to work fine but when I press the Button nothing happens, no error, no crash

Answer (score 1):

You need to notify update to recyclerview Adapter after adding new item in Todo Table.

First change the TodoDao as below

```
@Dao
interface TodoDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Todo")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<List<Todo>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Todo WHERE checked = 0")
    fun getUnchecked(): LiveData<List<Todo>>

    @Upsert
    fun upsert(vararg todo: Todo)

    @Delete
    fun delete(todo: Todo)
}
```

Update CustomAdapter as

```
    class CustomAdapter :
    Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var items: List<Todo> = emptyList()

    /**
     * Provide a reference to the type of views that you are using
     * (custom ViewHolder)
     */
    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val textView: TextView

        init {
            // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View
            textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView3)
        }
    }

    fun setItems(items: List<Todo>) {
        this.items = items
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        // Create a new view, which defines the UI of the list item
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_row, viewGroup, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        // Get element from your dataset at this position and replace the
        // contents of the view with that element
        viewHolder.textView.text = items[position].description
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun getItemCount() = items.size
}
```

Now update code in MainActivity as below

```
db.todoDao().getUnchecked().observe(this) {
    adapter.setItems(it)
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. That's another question I had but for now I was just trying to fix the button because it was no longer triggering and adding database entries. I will implement your code, though.